# getting object from arraylist using equals method - java

Tags: java, collections

I have a two list of objects. I want to compare both the lists. I have custom objects in these two lists. I thought i can override the equals method and get the object from the array list like - list.get(objectRef) and this should give the required object based on equals method comparison. But just came to know there is no such support yet.

Instead of looping through the entrie list and finding it, is there anyway that will give my required object from list by a single call. is it available in any apache utils lib or any external lib?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
list.get(list.indexOf(objectRef));
```

Comment: Be careful! If the object does not exist, indexOf() will return -1 and list.get() will throw an exception.